# Funciones - Retornado de objetos

Tags: python, function, parametros

Les traigo una duda que no consigo resolver y salvo error mío desde luego, no he encontrado en el resto de stack sobre el retornado de objetos desde funciones.

Llamada a la función de leer pasando como parámetro la ruta de la db y la query:

```
#recuperamos los parametros de conexión al ftp, guardados en la query
def ftp_config():
    sql = "SELECT server,user,pwd FROM ftp_conf"
    res = leer(db,sql)
    return res()

res = ftp_config
print(res)
```

Y éstas son las funciones que están en otro módulo:

```
def conectar(db):
    con = SQL.connect(db)
    #retornamos la conexion
    return con

def leer(db,sql):
    conectar(db,sql)

    #creamos el cursor para trabajar con la bbdd
    cursor = con.cursor()

    # Recuperamos los registros de la tabla de usuarios
    cursor.execute(sql)

    # devolvemos el resultado en formato tupla gracias al método fetchall
    return cursor.fetchall()

    #cerramos la conexion
    con.close()
```

y el resultado que obtengo es :

> <function ftp_config at 0x00000234D3A9C310>

Muchas gracias de antemano!!!!!!

Comment: Revertí la edición del título, no hace falta indicar en este que está resuelto el tema, la interfaz de usuario indica claramente cuando una pregunta tiene una respuesta aceptada, cosa que ya ha has hecho con tu pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: Ok! Gracias y disculpa je je

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error 1**

Esta función está definida con un parámetro.

```
def conectar(db):
    con = SQL.connect(db)
    #retornamos la conexion
    return con
```

luego la llamas con dos parámetros ...

```
conectar(db,sql)
```

**Error 2**

Llamas a `conectar` para obtener una conexión, pero desechas el resultado de la función, y luego ocupas la variable `con`, que no está definida dentro de `leer`, no se recibe como parámetro y tampoco es global.

```
def leer(db,sql):
    conectar(db,sql)

    #creamos el cursor para trabajar con la bbdd
    cursor = con.cursor()
```

**Error 3**

Retornas de la función

```
# devolvemos el resultado en formato tupla gracias al método fetchall
return cursor.fetchall()
```

Después de un `return`, lo que sigue (`close`) no se ejecuta nunca.

```
#cerramos la conexion
con.close()
```

**Error 4**

```
#recuperamos los parametros de conexión al ftp, guardados en la query
def ftp_config():
    sql = "SELECT server,user,pwd FROM ftp_conf"
    res = leer(db,sql)
    return res()
```

La función `leer` retorna una lista y `return res()` es no válido, ya que no puedes "llamar" a una lista como si fuera una función.

**Error 5**

Dentro de la misma función `ftp_config` la variable `db` no está definida, no se recibe como parámetro ni tampoco es global. ¿Qué valor tiene? No se sabe.

**Error 6**

```
res = ftp_config
print(res)
```

`ftp_config` es una función. Una función es un objeto. Puede ser asignado a otra variable. Eso es válido.

`ftp_config()` es una invocación a la función. Retorna un valor, que también puede ser asignado.

Cuando haces `print(res)`, estas imprimiendo una función, no el resultado de su ejecución.

**Lo que probablemente quieras es**

Sin garantías de corrección, esto parece ser lo que buscas

```
def conectar(db):
    con = SQL.connect(db)
    #retornamos la conexion
    return con

def leer(db,sql):
    con = conectar(db)

    #creamos el cursor para trabajar con la bbdd
    cursor = con.cursor()

    # Recuperamos los registros de la tabla de usuarios
    cursor.execute(sql)


    # devolvemos el resultado en formato tupla gracias al método fetchall
    lista = cursor.fetchall()

    #cerramos la conexion
    con.close()

    return lista

#recuperamos los parametros de conexión al ftp, guardados en la query
def ftp_config(db):
    sql = "SELECT server,user,pwd FROM ftp_conf"
    res = leer(db,sql)
    return res

db = ... algo que debe estar definido en alguna parte
res = ftp_config(db)
print(res)
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias!! Candid Moe. Funciona Perfecto!!!